# How to fix encoding with send-MailMessage in powerShell?

Tags: powershell, encoding, import-csv

I'm trying to send email message from a powershell script but in the email all accented characters (ó, é etc) get scrambled.

What I'm doing is the following:

1. I use Import-CSV to import an ANSI encoded file.
2. foreach($item in $inputfile)  send-MailMessage -Body $item.body -bodyAsHTML

I'm not a PC-user and the whole encoding thingy gives me headache.

I tried all the different encoding options of send-MailMessage without getting the expected result.

Comment: Have you noted that for import-csv' `ecoding` parameter "The default value is UTF8NoBOM"? Maybe your data is already broken *before* the `send-MailMessage`...

Comment: Thanks, I have missed that one. I'll check this out and see what I can do.

Comment: ...and that was basically it. Thanks for the tip although I'll never understand the encoding tragedy in windows. I used OEM to encode the files (to ANSI) and read the files with import-csv -encoding Default (whatever that is) and it magically works. :-)